# Without Completable.defer I don't know where my function works

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm confused. I not found any articles about that.
Check my example, in this case longOperation will work on Schedulers.io()

```
 private Completable longOperation() throws InterruptedException {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          return Completable.complete();
      }

    private void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        compositeDisposable.add(Completable.defer(() -> longOperation())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        customToast("long operation done");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }
                }));
    }
```

but if I will remove `Completable.defer(() -> longOperation()`

```
private void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        compositeDisposable.add(longOperation()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        customToast("long operation done");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }
                }));
    }
```

I don't know where.
**On which thread my method 'longOperation' will work ?** I ask because my UI is freezed after invoke doSomething without Completable.defer.

Comment: In second snippet, "`longOperation`" will work on the same thread that calls `doSomething()`. This might indeed be the UI thread, no way to know just by looking at these snippets. Thing is: you have the `Thread.sleep` inside the "`longOperation`", so that method will only finish when caret reaches the first `return` statement, which in your case is after 5 seconds and `x<1` milliseconds from calling the `doSomething()`.

Comment: u mean 1st snippet ? because in second `longOperation` didn't work on UI :)

Comment: No, I do mean the second snippet. And I didn't say it did work on UI - I said it will work on whatever thread that calls `doSomething()`, which **may or may not be** the UI thread.

Comment: I have problem with `longOperation`, not with `doSomething` :)

Comment: You asked "what thread does `longOperation` run on in second snippet". My answer is "whatever thread the `doSomething()` method was called on". Whether you have problem with `doSomething` or not, this fact will not change.